# Error the Card payments and Transfer in Capabilities keep PENDING in a Japanese Standard Stripe Connect Account In Test Mode

Tags: stripe-payments

I just stuck in this problem.
I'm trying to create a Japanese Standarad Stripe Connect Account in Test Mode .
I have used the test data as the Stripe recommended but my 2 fields Card payments and Transfer are still pending until now.

I have tried to create with a new key pair from another account, this time it works
=> both Card payments and Transfer fields are verified very quickly in just 3 or 5 minutes.

I don't know what is wrong with this account or this key pair ?

Anyone gets this error before ?

Comment: The connect test data should be used from [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing). If it's still not working, [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/contact/) will probably be the best place to go to.

Comment: yup, I tried. But, they still need time to figure out. Thus, I create this question with hope to find out somebody who got this problem

Answer (score 0):

My problem is just I did not log out stripe cli which was holding my old key pair. Thus, just check if the new key pair is already in the stripe cli when you try to test in local